# Codeigniter always returns the latest data?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using ZiscoERP script and in version 6.0.0 the loops are not working successfully in the Purchase Payment list. It always returns the most recently added data as many rows in the database. Below is the code of the relevant Controller.

```
public function purchaseList()
    {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $this->load->model('datatables');
            $this->datatables->table = 'tbl_purchases';
            $this->datatables->join_table = array('tbl_suppliers');
            $this->datatables->join_where = array('tbl_suppliers.supplier_id=tbl_purchases.supplier_id');
            $custom_field = custom_form_table_search(20);
            $action_array = array('purchase_id');
            $main_column = array('reference_no', 'tbl_suppliers.name', 'purchase_date', 'due_date', 'status', 'tags');
            $result = array_merge($main_column, $custom_field, $action_array);
            $this->datatables->column_order = $result;
            $this->datatables->column_search = $result;
            
            $this->datatables->order = array('purchase_id' => 'desc');
            $fetch_data = make_datatables();
            
            
            $data = array();
            
            $edited = can_action('152', 'edited');
            $deleted = can_action('152', 'deleted');
            foreach ($fetch_data as $_key => $v_purchase) {
                if (!empty($v_purchase)) {
                    $action = null;
                    $sub_array = array();
                    $can_edit = $this->purchase_model->can_action('tbl_purchases', 'edit', array('purchase_id' => $v_purchase->purchase_id));
                    $can_delete = $this->purchase_model->can_action('tbl_purchases', 'delete', array('purchase_id' => $v_purchase->purchase_id));
                    
                    $currency = $this->purchase_model->check_by(array('code' => config_item('default_currency')), 'tbl_currencies');
                    
                    $sub_array[] = '<a href="' . base_url() . 'admin/purchase/purchase_details/' . $v_purchase->purchase_id . '">' . ($v_purchase->reference_no) . '</a>';
                    $sub_array[] = !empty($v_purchase) ? '<span class="tags">' . $v_purchase->name . '</span>' : '-';
                    $sub_array[] = display_date($v_purchase->purchase_date);
                    $sub_array[] = display_money($this->purchase_model->calculate_to('purchase_due', $v_purchase->purchase_id), $currency->symbol);
                    $status = $this->purchase_model->get_payment_status($v_purchase->purchase_id);
                    if ($status == ('fully_paid')) {
                        $bg = "success";
                    } elseif ($status == ('partially_paid')) {
                        $bg = "warning";
                    } elseif ($status == ('not_paid')) {
                        $bg = "danger";
                    } elseif ($v_purchase->emailed == 'Yes') {
                        $bg = "info";
                    } else {
                        $bg = "danger";
                    }
                    
                    $sub_array[] = '<span class="badge bg-' . $bg . '">' . lang($status) . '</span>';
                    $sub_array[] = get_tags($v_purchase->tags, true);
                    
                    $custom_form_table = custom_form_table(20, $v_purchase->purchase_id);
                    
                    if (!empty($custom_form_table)) {
                        foreach ($custom_form_table as $c_label => $v_fields) {
                            $sub_array[] = $v_fields;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!empty($can_edit) && !empty($edited)) {
                        $action .= btn_edit('admin/purchase/new_purchase/' . $v_purchase->purchase_id) . ' ';
                    }
                    if (!empty($can_delete) && !empty($deleted)) {
                        $action .= ajax_anchor(base_url("admin/purchase/delete_purchase/" . $v_purchase->purchase_id), "<i class='btn btn-xs btn-danger fa fa-trash-o'></i>", array("class" => "", "title" => lang('delete'), "data-fade-out-on-success" => "#table_" . $_key)) . ' ';
                    }
                    $action .= btn_view('admin/purchase/purchase_details/' . $v_purchase->purchase_id) . ' ';
                    if (!empty($can_edit) && !empty($edited)) {
                        $action .= '<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Payment" href="' . base_url() . 'admin/purchase/payment/' . $v_purchase->purchase_id . '">' . lang('pay') . '</a>';
                    }
                    $sub_array[] = $action;
                    $data[] = $sub_array;
                }
            }
            
            render_table($data);
        } else {
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
    }
```

Here you can see my current data;

[Here you can see my current data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKrC5.png)

This is my real data;

[This is my real data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ1X1.png)

I expected all the data in my database to be reflected on my page with a foreach loop, but only the last data I added was written with the loop.

Comment: could you please make this a bit clearer: what do you want as output? `current data` or `real data` ? or something in between?

Comment: I want all the values ​​of the table present in the database.